# Получение параметров GET и POST запросов для последующей обработки

Tags: python, django, post, get

Необходимо в проекте на Django реализовать обработку GET и POST запросов к БП (`sqlite3`). Если с GET запросом хоть как-то получается (хотя не понимаю, можно ли весь перечень параметров запроса получить для последующей обработке по условиям), то с POST запросом (в данном случае пытаюсь реализовать добавление нового объекта в БП) ничего не выходит. Он просто не добавляется и все.

Класс обработки запросов выглядит следующим образом:

```py
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        print('Get request: ', a)
        arg = request.GET.get('last_name')
        person = Guests.objects.filter(last_name=arg)
        return HttpResponse(person[0].last_name + ' ' + person[0].first_name)

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            new_guest = Guests()
            new_guest.first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
            new_guest.last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
            new_guest.age = request.POST.get('age')
            new_guest.save()
        return HttpResponse('New guest successfully added!')
```

В данном примере POST запрос

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/search/?first_name=Misha&last_name=Fateev&age=35"
```

не сохраняет пользователя в БД. При запросе GET

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/search/?last_name=Ivanov"
```

postman выводит только одного человека (хотя удовлетворяющих условию несколько). Я понимаю, что это потому что указано выводить данные первого объект ([0]). Однако не могу сообразить, как получить доступ ко всем элементам, удовлетворяющим условию.
Буду очень признателен за советы, сам бьюсь над решение уже больше двух дней.

Comment: насколько я понимаю `Guests` это модель, используй `Guests.objects.create(first_name=request.POST.get('first_name'), last_name=request.POST.get('last_name'), ...)` а вообще если это рест апи, то стоит использовать сериалайзер

Насчет get что выводит одного только, вы сами пишите `person[0]` пройдитесь циклом по person занесите все в нужный формат и выведете  через HttpResponse

Comment: Проблема в том, что `request.POST.get('first_name')` возвращает None. Т.е. добавление в БД не происходит, потому что этот метод возвращает пустые поля. Пробовал искать решение проблемы по аналогичным ситуациям - к сожалению ничего не нашел. `self.request.POST.get('first_name')` также возвращает None.

Comment: а, я не заметил, POST запрос идет с параметрами? Вам необходимо передавать данные при POST запросе через body. Через Postman https://hkar.ru/158ok обратите внимание что я нахожусь на вкладке body и правее указан что формат входных данных JSON, а слева от url указан POST запрос. 
или через консоль как то так curl -d '{"first_name":"Ivan", "last_name":"Ivanoc"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/search/ Подробнее погуглите про пост запросы

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю господина maestro за помощь! Теперь понял в чем была проблема (данные запроса необходимо было посылать через body), получилось найти информацию и все исправить. Еще раз спасибо!